# Can replication be set up when already mirroring?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, mirroring

We currently use SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition and we mirror from one SQL Server instance to another for automatic failover purposes.

I want to replicate the database which is mirrored, to another SQL Server instance, for reporting purposes.  The replication will need to be as close to real time as possible.

**Questions**

- Can you have SQL Server replication working alongside mirroring?
- If so, how does it function and does it have constraints / impact on the mirroring?

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely setup transactional replication on mirrored publishing databases. It is fully supported, and [Microsoft has some good content on getting it up and running](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151799(v=sql.110).aspx).

The only caveats are the ones that already exist for transactional replication, and the recommendation to have the distributor database on another server outside of the mirrored pair.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  What is the impact if any on turning replication on for the primary production SERVER?

Comment: From an impact perspective, you'll see heavy IO during the snapshot phase (unless you initialize from a backup). Other than that, increased memory usage in windows (for the agents), but not a significant one. You will also want to be more aware of transaction log usage, as a dead subscriber will prevent log clearing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all different types of replication work with mirroring.

You may have a performance impact, which cannot be assessed with the information you provide. However, it would be minimal with respect to the mirroring, it just adds resource usage on your master; but similar concerns to what you should evaluate for replication in a non-mirrored database.

However, you may prefer to consider snapshots in concert with mirroring, as a solution for reporting purposes.

References:

Database Mirroring and Database Snapshots

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175511.aspx

Database Mirroring and Replication (SQL Server)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151799.aspx